# Is there a way to style a textfield to show a labeled image inside my text?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield

Good evening!

I want to display a uncommon layout into a HTML Textfield, using AS3/Flash CS4.
This is what I need to create, is it possible?
 
http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/6931/as3textlayout.jpg

I have tried some CSS styles, but I didn't found any way to align a span to the left.
TLF is out of my range, the related project is closed to CS4, but if it is the only way, someone tell me!

Thanks!

Comment: Is this flash or html?  You are being slightly vague and have tagged the question with CSS

Comment: is about using CSS into Flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use HTMLText and simply have a span and an img tag.

Comment: Can you be more specific?
Did you tried this or have a working example?

Comment: @Marelo I would encourage you to read up on some css and html.  It should then all become clear.  Just google 'css and html tutorials'

Comment: @Lime, I'm not talking about HTML+CSS, my question is about CSS into Adobe Flash textfields.

Comment: @Marcelo sorry I can't help with adobe flash.... I'm on linux currently and I only have ever used photoshop and premiere.  I wish I could help.